# is there away for me to alter this code so that it produces an output that can be stored as a 2d list?

Tags: python, list, recursion, 2d, maze

I can print a random maze with this piece of code:

I​ want to store this to a 2d list so that I can edit it.

I have tried editing itself but this code is designed to just be printed, and nothing else.

```
def random_maze(w = 16, h = 8):
    vis = [[0] * w + [1] for _ in range(h)] + [[1] * (w + 1)]
    ver = [["|  "] * w + ['|'] for v in range(h)] + [[]]
    hor = [["+--"] * w + ['+'] for v in range(h + 1)]

    def go(x, y):
        vis[y][x] = 1

        d = [(x - 1, y), (x, y + 1), (x + 1, y), (x, y - 1)]
        shuffle(d)
        for (xx, yy) in d:
            if vis[yy][xx]: continue
            if xx == x: hor[max(y, yy)][x] = "+  "
            if yy == y: ver[y][max(x, xx)] = "   "
            go(xx, yy)

    go(randrange(w), randrange(h))

    s = ""
    for (a, b) in zip(hor, ver):
        s += ''.join(a + ['\n'] + b + ['\n'])
    return s
```

I want the code output to be like [['+--', '+--'....etc
so that I can edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have do to is a small change in the part where you join `a` and `b` into `s`. You need to have an additional variable `matrix` to store the 2D list:

```
s = ""
matrix = []
for (a, b) in zip(hor, ver):
    s += ''.join(a + ['\n'] + b + ['\n'])
    matrix.append(a)
    matrix.append(b)
return s, matrix
```

and finally you can retrieve the results like that:

```
stringMatrix, matrix = random_maze()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution. Use the np.append function to add your maze in a 2d-array:

```
from random import randrange, shuffle
import numpy as np
w = 10
h = 10
vis = [[0] * w + [1] for _ in range(h)] + [[1] * (w + 1)]
ver = [["|  "] * w + ['|'] for v in range(h)] + [[]]
hor = [["+--"] * w + ['+'] for v in range(h + 1)]

def go(x, y):
    vis[y][x] = 1

    d = [(x - 1, y), (x, y + 1), (x + 1, y), (x, y - 1)]
    shuffle(d)
    for (xx, yy) in d:
        if vis[yy][xx]: continue
        if xx == x: hor[max(y, yy)][x] = "+  "
        if yy == y: ver[y][max(x, xx)] = "   "
        go(xx, yy)

go(randrange(w), randrange(h))

s = ""

twoD_matrix = np.append([hor[0]], [ver[0]], axis=0)

for i in range(1, len(hor)):
    twoD_matrix = np.append(twoD_matrix, [hor[i], ver[1]], axis = 0)


print(twoD_matrix)
```

Or if you prefer a list of lists you can do like this:

```
from random import randrange, shuffle
import numpy as np
w = 10
h = 10
vis = [[0] * w + [1] for _ in range(h)] + [[1] * (w + 1)]
ver = [["|  "] * w + ['|'] for v in range(h)] + [[]]
hor = [["+--"] * w + ['+'] for v in range(h + 1)]

def go(x, y):
    vis[y][x] = 1

    d = [(x - 1, y), (x, y + 1), (x + 1, y), (x, y - 1)]
    shuffle(d)
    for (xx, yy) in d:
        if vis[yy][xx]: continue
        if xx == x: hor[max(y, yy)][x] = "+  "
        if yy == y: ver[y][max(x, xx)] = "   "
        go(xx, yy)

go(randrange(w), randrange(h))

s = ""

twoD_list = []

for i in range(len(hor)):
    twoD_list.append(hor[i])
    twoD_list.append(ver[i])

print(twoD_list)
```